# How to reuse j2me kxml parser?

Tags: parsing, java-me, xml-parsing, kxml

I am useing kxml parser for my j2me application. I am reading the file from phone memory and parsing the xml file to display the data(have various level of filter). On each filter i need to read the data from this file. For first time i created the parser and every time i re-assign this parser1(reference-original) to the paerser2(used to parse data). For first time i got the correct answer, but second time i haven't got the file content it shows null as data.

Here is my code:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(rmsObj.rmsData.elementAt(0).toString());
InputStream in = fc.openInputStream();
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
commonAppObj.externParser = new XmlParser(is);
```

commonAppObj class file.

```
protected void fileread() {
    try {
        if(externParser != null){
            parser = externParser;
            fileparser(parser);
        }else{
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.dataBase);
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
            parser = new XmlParser(is);
            fileparser(parser);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } finally {
        parser = null;
    }
}

private void fileparser(XmlParser parser){
    try {
        ParseEvent event = null;
        dataflag = 0;
        dataflagS = 0;
        System.out.println("findtags = " + findtags);
        while (((event = parser.read()).getType() != Xml.END_DOCUMENT) && (dataflag != 1)) {
            if (event.getType() == Xml.START_TAG) {
                String name = event.getName();
                if (name != null && name.equals(findtags)) {
                    dataflag = 0;
                    parseAddressTag(parser);
                }
                name = null;
            }
            event = null;
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } finally {
        parser = null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/InputStream.html) returns true in a call to [markSupported](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29) you may [`reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) it at the end of `fileparser` method, but first you need to call [`mark`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/InputStream.html#mark%28int%29) right after creating it.

```
if (in.markSupported()) {
  in.mark(in.available());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But when i tried this i got this error java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr Telmo Pimentel Mota. I have completed this task. The change i made to the code was "in.mark(fc.filesize())" and the reset works fine now ..

Comment: It is good to know that it worked. If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct. :)